# Show deafult autocompletion results when MultiAutoCompleteTextView gets foucs

Tags: android

In `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` i am displaying auto completion results from my sqlite database. Means i have set custom adapter for MultiAutoCompleteTextView.

Now I want to autocomplete default results when `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` gets focus.

eg. if i click on `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, it should autocomplete default (starting from any specific letter) results.

How can i do that ?..

Answer (score 0):

Extend the MultiAutoCompleteTextView class, and override the onFocusChanged method:

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused) {
        performFiltering(getText(), -1);
    }
}
```

(I did this for a regular AutoCompleteTextView but I assume it will also work for a Multi...)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  Looking at the source code I don't see how this will pull up default autosuggest results.